# Python: How to send HOG descriptors as an input vector to a Neural Network using PyBrain

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain, scikit-image

I've extracted HOG features and labelled them to form a training set using Python (Scikit-image & OpenCV).

The Python user-defined function is 'compute_hog' and the code is given below:

```
# Function definition of 'compute_hog'
def compute_hog(imagename):
        image = color.rgb2gray(imagename)
        fd, hog_image = hog(image,orientations=8,pixels_per_cell=(16,16),cells_per_block=(1,1),visualise=True)
        return fd  # return the feature descriptors


# A sample training set with 3 images is created
list=[] # Create a 2D list with 3 rows
list.append([])
list.append([])
list.append([])


# call 'compute_hog' function and store the HOG descriptors in a 2D list
# For this example, I've used only 3 images
counter=0       
for imgs in lst:
    list[counter].append(compute_hog(imgs))
    counter=counter+1

# Assign labels to the corresponding 3 Features
list[0].append('Label1')
list[1].append('Label2')
list[2].append('Label3')
```

The 'list' variable consists the HOG Feature Label pairs for the corresponding 3 images.

**How to convert this variable to an input vector and pass it to a Multi-Layer Feed Forward Neural Network (created using Pybrain) for Network training and Classification ?**

Using **Backpropagation algorithm**, the test image should be classified as Valid if it matches the Features of the training set, else it is invalid.

**How to classify the test image using PyBrain ?**